# how to display xml into a html table

Tags: xml, xslt, element

i am trying to output the values of the attribute Local int a an html table. And I would like to output the first value of local into row1 and second value of local into row2. i wonder how i am to do that? i am very new to xml.Thanks

```
    <FoodItems>
            <food   Local = "Yes" >
                <Name>Rice</Name>
                <Brand>Jasmine</Brand>
                <Price>$89</price>
                <Grade>A</grade>
            </food> 
            <food   Local = "No" >
                <Name>Beans</Name>
                <Brand>MrBean</Brand>
                <Price>$56</price>
                <Grade>A</grade>
            </food>

    </FoodItems>
```

Comment: Get yourself a decent open source JavaScript XML parser.

Comment: Please edit your other question instead of posting a new one.